# If statement using a json response

Tags: php, arrays, json, if-statement, response

What is the correct way to use an if statement with a json response?

This is my current code.

```html
<?php
$link =file_get_contents('xxxxxxxxxx');
$res=json_decode($link, true);
echo "Currently: ";
if ($res['response'][0]['personastate'] == '1') {
echo "Online";
else {
echo "Offline";
}
?>
```

Printing the response via

```html
print $res['response'][0]['personastate'];
```

works just fine, resulting in a 1 or a 0 being printed.

Where did I go wrong? I can't find any information on anything similar to my problem.

Comment: change `else if ` to `else` if you don't want to set a condition, and adjust the brackets

Comment: And you're missing a closing bracket for if and opening bracket for else

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` isn't formatted correctly.  Try this instead:

```
<?php
  $link = file_get_contents('xxxxxxxxxx');
  $res = json_decode($link, true);
  echo "Currently: ";
  if ($res['response'][0]['personastate'] == '1') {
    echo "Online";
  } // Don't forget your close-brace on the if
  else { // And re-open it on the else.
    echo "Offline";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you for pointing that out. I appreciate it.